# MYSQL LEFT JOIN Returning Null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables ,

Table 1 & table 2

Need to compare : component_name with product and component_version with version
if those values are same then fetch corresponding cvid from table2

Table 2 & table 3

Now with respect to the table 2 - cvid value is equal to table 3 - cvid value
(in-sence values should be equal) exact string match

i have tried with tables

Table 1 : upload_bom

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `upload_bom` (
  `component_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `component_version` varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
```

Table 2 : cpe_cse

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cpe_cse` (
  `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cpe` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `argument` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `vendor` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `product` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `version` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `subversion` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `platform` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cvid` varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
```

Table 3: cses

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cses` (
  `cvid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cvss` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(5000) NOT NULL
)
```

Hence i have tried an code ,

but when i try to join cpe_csv.cvid = cses.cvid , i get null values but the same query works in sqlite not in MySQL

below is the query i tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT upload_bom.component_name, upload_bom.component_version, cpe_cse.cvid, cses.cvid, cses.description
FROM upload_bom
LEFT JOIN cpe_cse on upload_bom.component_name = cpe_cse.product AND upload_bom.component_version = cpe_cse.version
LEFT JOIN cses on cpe_cse.cvid = cses.cvid
```

i have to display something like

```
Select upload.bom_Component_name, upload_bom.component_version, cpe_cse.cvid, cses.cvid, cses.description
       component_name , component_version , cpe_cse.cvid, cses.cvid, cses.description
       "freebsd","1.1","cv1999-0001","cv1999-0001", "this is an software"
```

while joining two columns of two tables iam getting null values , i wann to over come it and join the tables

Comment: If you're getting null values, then it means there's no match for those values. Show some sample data that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: when it comes to null values, did you try inner join?

Comment: If you use `LEFT JOIN` and there's no match, you get null values for the columns from the second table. If you use `INNER JOIN`, it only returns rows where all 3 tables could be joined.

Comment: yes i tried inner join but no value returned

Comment: it might be because there are no matches.

Comment: inner join returned as empty result set

Comment: Show the relevant data which should be joined - just the relevant rows.

Comment: cpe_cse.cvid = cses.cvid , these two tables has to join  , where  cpe_cse.cvid = "cv2001-0001"  , cses.cvid = "cv2001-0001" , like wise i have the data